# Task :app:compileJava FAILED: file does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, compiler-errors, war

I'm trying to build a war file for my java project by using gradle task. However,I feep getting this error, but I do have ajc.options in my project, What did I do wrong?

```
Working Directory: C:\Users\weihsiang\Documents\危害鑑別\backend_api
Gradle user home: C:\Users\weihsiang\.gradle
Gradle Distribution: Gradle wrapper from target build
Gradle Version: 7.6
Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Build Scans Enabled: false
Offline Mode Enabled: false
Gradle Tasks: war


> Task :app:compileJava
[error] build config error: file does not exist: C:\Users\weihsiang\Documents\�摰喲�\backend_api\app\build\tmp\compileJava\ajc.options
    
[error] no sources specified
    

2 errors

> Task :app:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed with exit code 2; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.